# Why is DirectFB not more widely used in GNU/Linux? Are there crippling limitations to it that don't exist in X11?

Tags: graphics, gtk, x11, directfb

As far as I understand, DirectFB offers hardware acceleration for many kinds of graphics cards. Additionally, it's smaller, faster, and uses up less memory than X11. Why then, is it not more mainstream than it is now?

Here's what I'm really unsure about: Do common GTK+/Qt programs need to be ported to it? On the DirectFB site, there's a project for porting Firefox to it. Why is that even necessary, if GTK+ has the ability to use DirectFB directly? The way I (probably incorrectly) understand it, is that Firefox should output to GTK+, which should output to DirectFB, which should output to the hardware. Please correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: firefox doesn't directly use Gtk+; it just uses its theme engine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're stressing about X as a source of overhead on a modern Linux system you probably aren't looking in the right place. X was designed a really long time ago for computers much less powerful than a modern cell phone.

If you look at "top" and see X using memory, there's a lot of work to do to figure out the actual X overhead. There are memory maps that aren't "real" memory, and there are resources (such as big blocks of pixels) allocated on behalf of apps. Bottom line the memory shown for X in top isn't what one might think.

People also hear that X uses the "network" and think this is going to be a performance bottleneck. "Network" here means local UNIX domain socket, which has negligible overhead on modern Linux. Things that would bottleneck on the network, there are X extensions to make fast (shared memory pixmaps, DRI, etc.). Threads in-process wouldn't necessarily be faster than the X socket, because the bottlenecks have more to do with the inherent problem of coordinating multiple threads or processes accessing the same hardware, than with the minimal overhead of local sockets.

The multi-process setup has a lot of advantages, such as being much harder to crash. See Google Chrome for example, using multiple processes to be more robust - and it turns out, also to run fast. Less processes does not necessarily mean more modern.

There are many reasons apps using GTK don't transparently port to DirectFB. For Firefox, one is that it uses X directly sometimes. Also, some toolkit-independent stuff such as the browser plugin interface uses X directly. Flash plugin would not work on DirectFB for example. Even apps that don't use X directly would often assume the normal X-based desktop environment exists (GNOME, etc.).

Another issue with replacing X is driver support, where both of the better graphics cards (NVidia, ATI) have proprietary drivers that are a good bit more capable than the free drivers, and those proprietary drivers are tied to X.

And of course there's migration path. If you have hundreds of apps using X and no clear end-user downside to X, nobody is going to switch to something where no apps work. Most likely, the solution here would be a rootless X server running on a new window system, so old apps still work.

Old is not always bad. X was very well-designed by smart people, and that has allowed it to evolve and change and still work many years later.

Anyway all a long way of saying, basically switching away from X is tons of effort, it really works fine, and "works fine" has never applied to any of the alternatives (at least if you want to be able to run most apps on most hardware).

There are issues with X - such as the impossibility of doing an atomic screen update, something the Wayland project is looking at - but most of the issues are really cosmetic for users (e.g. non-atomic updates) or cosmetic for developers (old deprecated extensions and the like). It just isn't true that one could drop X and magically have something much smaller and faster. That's mostly based on people speculating that "old" and "uses network" must be slow and bloated, but again, X was designed for really really crappy hardware. I used to run X (and Emacs!) fine on my 386 with maybe 8 megs of RAM or something like that.

Comment: X is crap.  The main reason it hasn't improved the way it should have is mainly because of all the secrecy and the patent issues in the computer graphics industry.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about implementation limitations (especially drivers) in the open source implementation of X. Those would apply to DirectFB too. The problems here are not inherent to the X protocol/design/API vs. some other possible design, they are more to do with (as you say) "logistical" issues such as ability to use the hardware.

Comment: @HavocP: You're missing an important detail, in regards to "X was designed a really long time ago for computers much less powerful than a modern cell phone."  The X Server itself, was not designed originally for the purposes it's utilized today.  The entire stack was not intended to run entirely on a single PC.  This explains the whole latency issues, the extreme importance to portability, and the significant level of hardware abstraction.  Fast forward to the present, we have a number of extensions to help adapt X11 for today's architecture. At its heart and soul, it's sub-optimal.

Comment: I certainly agree that X is suboptimal and do think Wayland has useful improvements on X and may finally be successful in replacing it... not coincidentally because Kristian (Wayland creator) understands X very well. The window system can be improved upon and simplified given modern requirements. But X is good enough that replacing it is a lot harder than it appears.

Answer (score 9):

x11 is much more than just a way to draw to a screen -  it's an entire network-capable desktop protocol suite. [DirectFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB) does not intend to replace x11 (as far as I know) but rather runs parallel to it. That is, DirectFB strives to be a lightweight "host" for applications needing access to basic input and graphic output. It is possible that an X server (the server in X is the thing that displays things :-) is written to use DirectFB.

[GTK on DirectFB is different than GTK on X11](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103061504/http://www.directfb.org/wiki/index.php/Projects:GTK_on_DirectFB)

Comment: I get it, GTK+ is different depending on the platform. However, I see that DirectFB has quite a few advanced features, and that X11 can't even do common procedures like alpha blending without additional modules. What gives?

Answer (score 7):

Simple, because DirectFB doesn't solve any problem. For embedded systems it's fine, but for desktop, you lose a lot and don't gain really anything.

Answer (score 5):

[DirectFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB) was designed for embedded systems, which have small memory footprint. It allows applications to talk directly to video hardware through a direct API, speeding up and simplifying graphic operations.

It is often used by games and embedded systems developers to circumvent the overhead of a full X Window System server implementation.

http://elinux.org/DirectFB

Answer (score 3):

X11 is far more portable than DirectFB.  An X11 app can run on Linux, BSD, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, MacOS X, Windows (via Cygwin or Exceed), and many more platforms.  DirectFB is pretty much Linux-only.

Answer (score 1):

With [XDirectFB](https://web.archive.org/web/20150324105419/http://www.directfb.org/index.php?path=Projects%2FXDirectFB) there is a rootless X Server using DirectFB.